# Discord.JS Bot Delete Own Message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Trying to get the bot to send a message and then 30 seconds later delete it's own message.
Can anyone help since I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined

The code

```
message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '>, the email you provided is not valid, sorry.')
            .then(function (message) {
              message.react("")
              message.react("")
            })
            .then(message => {
                message.delete({ timeout: 10000 /*time unitl delete in milliseconds*/});
            })
            .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I am not sure but when you invoke `.then` first, the message object is already consumed so when you use `.then` there is nothing left. Can you try using `message.delete` inside the first `.then` method?

Comment: Amazing, that was simple! Thank you - that fixed it :-) I hadn't realised that was the case. Do you want to post as an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.then` method, the `message` object is already consumed and there is nothing left when you invoke the second `.then` method, and using `.delete` on a message with options probably is global in discord.js message objects so you probably can invoke it in first `then` block.

```js
message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '>, the email you provided is not valid, sorry.')
            .then(function (message) {
              message.react("")
              message.react("")
              message.delete({ timeout: 10000 /*time unitl delete in milliseconds*/});
            })
            .catch(console.error);
```